# How do I attach an event handler to Bing maps push pin

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, bing-maps, pushpin

I'm trying to attach an event handler to my push pin. Can anyone help?  Here's what I have so far:

```vb
' Retrieve the center of the current map view.
Dim mapCenter = Map1.Center

' Create a pushpin to put at the center of the view.
Dim pin1 As New Pushpin()
pin1.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)

pin1.Location = New Location(52.499634, -1.705241)
```

Also, if I drag the map, the push pin stays where it is rather than moving with the map. How do I make it move with the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when the pin is tapped by registering for the `LeftMouseButtonUp` event. This works close enough as makes no observable difference to detecting taps.

Location is relative to the host control.
You need to set the Location to a `GeoCoordinate` for a pin to move with the map.